# Cplex would not run on Matlab

Tags: matlab, mex, cplex, win64

I have just downloaded Cplex 12.8 and wanted to run cplexlp.m instead of linprog.m in my Matlab workspace (Matlab x64 2016b).
However, even when I added the path and saved it as

> > addpath 'C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\cplex\matlab\x64_win64'
> >
> > savepath

I get the follwoing message when trying to solve LP

> > cplexlp(1,[],[],[],[],0,Inf)

Error using cplexlp
Invalid MEX-file 'C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\cplex\matlab\x64_win64\cplexlink1280.mexw64':
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\cplex\matlab\x64_win64\cplexlink1280.mexw64 is not a valid Win32
application..

This is odd, since my Windows, Matlab and Cplex are all 64-bit.
Is this because cplex 12.8 does not support Matlab 2016? If so, what options will I have?

Comment: The [detailed system requirements](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019100) specify exactly what is supported with CPLEX 12.8. For example, it looks like MATLAB R2016a 9.0 is supported (and more).

Comment: Thank you @rkersh. I had already looked into the link but nowhere could I find the specific requirement for Matlab version (Only Windows specifications). Anyway, I still get the mentioned error.

Comment: In case you didn't figure it out yet, once you get to the detailed system requirements page, make sure "Version 12.8.0" is selected. Then, click on "Windows", followed by the "Prerequisites" tab, and finally scroll down to the "Development Tools" section. That should show you a table of the supported MATLAB versions.

Comment: As stated in the [Setting up CPLEX for MATLAB](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/MATLAB/topics/gs_install.html), did you install the appropriate Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package? That is, the 2015 Redistributable Package (x64), that can be downloaded [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685).

Comment: Here's one more thing to check. Did you happen to have a 32-bit MATLAB version installed at one point? [This](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/30096-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-matlab) MATLAB forum post seems to hint that you can get the error you're reporting if it isn't properly cleaned up.